# Do new Apple SDKs patch previous releases?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

A new iPhone will be soon out there along a new iOS release. Sooner or later there will also be a Xcode upgrade with the SDK for iOS 6

Does Apple do any type of bugfix on previous SDKs or are bugfixes just solved on new releases?

As an example: Core Data with iCloud still have some issues but it is getting better over time. Let's say I have an app that really depends on that combo. I would require iOS6, however not all users upgrade the handsets. Ideally an app compiled with a newer XCode release could patch some error on previous SDKs if the target is set to an older iOS release.

Should I expect that a project compiled with future SDK releases to work better on devices running on older iOS versions? will be some SDKs bugfixes backported?

I understand that there are some bugs that cannot be fixed without an iOS update on the client. Also that it is a lot of work (and unlikely) to backport bugfixes. I am just wondering what is the normal release policy of Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new SDK may enable some new features on old iOS versions due to new constants or functions becoming documented, but it won't fix anything.

You can be reasonably sure at this point there will never be an iOS 5.2. Bugs are here to stay, unless they're security issues and Apple decides to do a security release. I doubt they'll bother, as only the original iPad is being abandoned over this ugprade.